# How did he enter the locked room?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-trek-deep-space-nine

In s01e04 episode of *Deep Space 9*, *A Man Alone*, the victim was a clone. Somehow, they found out that the original was the killer.

But, **how did he get into the locked room?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s actually given in plain sight at the murder scene, although we don’t realise it then.

The door was opened twice :

- First time for the checkin
- Second time 13 minutes later … “we have to assume that’s when the killer left”

Sisko then adds “[the killer] might have entered the Holosuite the same time Ibudan did “

Sisko was right - original Ibudan entered with the clone, then left through the door 13 minutes later.

Comment: Coming to think of it, they didn't elaborate on the clone. Did he know that he was a clone? What was his relationship with the original? If they entered the room together, then they came together and do other stuff together?

Comment: Yes, there’s a lot unanswered that we’re left to speculate. We can say that clones do somehow get their donor’s memories and personality (otherwise the one at the end would not be “a living breathing member of Bajoran society”, and also killing a clone is murder) so my guess is that Original was in disguise ever since the clone was “born”, so the clone did not know he was a clone, nor that he was going to get murdered (somehow the original erased that part of his memories).  So clone has a fellow-traveler, who suggested an excellent massage experience ….

Comment: Indeed, the original was in disguise. About the memory to get murdered--the clone could have been conceived afterwards. But his brings us back to the original problem. The masseuse was a hologram woman that the killer pushed aside. So, if the clone didn't know the killer, then how did the killer get into the room without the clone knowing about it?

Comment: Clone and Original entered the room together, so clone knew Original was there.  That much is certain, but everything else (how much else did the clone know? was Original in disguise? etc) are just guesses.

Comment: Okay, so the whole point wasn't conveyed properly. No matter the relationship, two separate beings were in the room, aware of each other. So, the chapter was supposed to say, "the killer came with the victim, and they knew each other; who is the killer, and what's the motivation?" Wasn't this supposed to be the first conclusion? The whole locked room mystery and the implication of a shape shifter being the main suspect don't make sense.

Comment: Yes, the script was a bit casual and confused.  Iit wasn’t really a traditional “locked room” mystery, where none could have been in the room with the victim at the time of the murder.  On the contrary,  they knew the door opened the second time when the killer left.  I think what was troubling them was no killer’s DNA, which implied killer was not there for long enough to leave any, from which they assumed the two did not arrive together.

Comment: Why is the DNA an issue? It's not time dependent, and one can be careful not to leave any behind. If you recall, the doctor had to do a thorough sweep of the victim's quarters to barely find a trace of someone who _slept_ there. And they didn't comment on finding anything strange in the crime scene like they commented on the victim's quarters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133659/discussion-between-racraman-and-zohar-levi).